# How to prove that average complexity is N/2 for linear search in the unsorted array

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, arrays, average-case, searching

All tutorials on algorithms show the complexity for the linear search in the unsorted array in the average case as `N/2`. I understand that the average case means the items in the list are randomly distributed.

Can anyone show how I would arrive at `N/2` if I have items randomly distributed? Or does it come out of randomly shuffling array bazillion times and recording the number of operations?

Comment: see this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71547/why-does-linear-search-have-fracn2-comparisons-on-average/71548#71548

Comment: Are you aware of the definition of expected values?

Comment: @Raphael, probably not, is that relevant here?

Comment: Yes. See fade2black's answer. My feeling is that if you know that definition, the rest is pretty immediate.

Comment: @Raphael, thanks, I'll also read about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First assume input is uniformly distributed. More precisely it is $\frac{n+1}{2}$. When you search for a particular element $x$ in an array of size $n$, that element may be located at the position either $1$, or $2$, $\dots$ or $n$. When we search we check each element in the array and compare it with $x$, and so when we reach $k^\text{th}$ element of the array we have already done $k$ comparisons.

If it is at $1$ then you find it in 1 comparison, if it is at $2$, you find it in 2 comparisons, $\dots$, if it is at $n$ then you do $n$ comparison in order to find it. In order to average it you sum the total number of comparisons $1+2+\dots + n = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$ and divide it by $n$ (size of the array) resulting in $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

---

More formal proof:
Assume that the input has uniform probability and the the size of the array is $n$. Let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of comparisons. Then $p(X=x)$ will denote the probability that we do $x$ comparisons. Since the distribution is uniform, $p(X=x) =\frac{1}{n}$. Once we formally defined our probability distribution now we can calculate the average number of comparisons in the linear search. What we do is compute the expected value 
$$E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^{n}{xp(x)} = \sum_{x=1}^{n}{\frac{x}{n}} = \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{2}{n} + \dots +\frac{n}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2}$$

Comment: got it, thanks, so why is it often stressed that the array should be randomly distributed?

Comment: @Maximus Notion of **Average** or **expected** number of steps has meaning only in context of some probability distribution. In other words, "array should be randomly distributed" means that input comes in a random way, i.e. if you know that input consists of positive integers between 1 and $n$ then randomly distributed means that any permutation on that integers is possible. In my answer I assumed that any permutation has equal probability, known as **uniform distribution**.

Comment: @Maximus For example if know that your input is always $1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10$, then you don't need to search over all array. You just need to check if $x <1$ or $x>10$, if it is true then $x$ is not found,  otherwise found. You just need only one comparison. This is an example of "lack" of randomness.